# Are open streams automatically flushed and closed on SIGINT in C?

Tags: c, posix, signals

I've read in a man page that when `exit()` is called all streams are flushed and closed automatically. At first I was skeptical as to how this was done and whether it is truly reliable but seeing as I can't find out any more I'm going to accept that it just works — we'll see if anything blows up. Anyway, if this stream closing behavior is present in `exit()` is such behavior also present in the default handler for `SIGINT` (the interrupt signal usually triggered with Ctrl+C)? Or, would it be necessary to do something like this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void onInterrupt(int dummy) { exit(0); }

int main() {
   signal(SIGINT, onInterrupt);
   FILE *file = fopen("file", "a");
   for (;;) { fprintf(file, "bleh"); } }
```

to get `file` to be closed properly? Or can the `signal(SIG...` and `void onInterrupt(...` lines be safely omitted?

Please restrict any replies to C, C99, and POSIX as I'm not using GNU libc. Thanks.

Comment: It's definitely closed. All file descriptors are released as the process ends. I'm not sure whether they are flushed though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C99 spec 7.19.3 has a weaker guarantee:

> 5 If the main
>   function returns to its original caller, or if the exit function is called, all open files are closed (hence all output streams are flushed) before program termination. Other paths to
>   program termination, such as calling the abort function, need not close all files
>   properly.
>
> 4 A file may be disassociated from a controlling stream by closing the file. Output streams
>   are flushed (any unwritten buffer contents are transmitted to the host environment) before
>   the stream is disassociated from the file.

So in C99, if it's closed then it's flushed.

The [POSIX exit function](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exit.html) has more details, in particular that whether `_exit` closes streams is implementation defined.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to handle the signal if you want your buffers flushed. Otherwise the process will be terminated and the file descriptors closed without flushing the stdio buffers.

Comment: This is correct.  By default, a SIGINT will terminate the process *abnornally*.  Processes so terminated do not call exit() and so do not have buffers flushed.

Comment: Flushing buffers from a signal handler invokes undefined behavior in almost all cases. The only way it wouldn't is if you can ensure that no async-signal-unsafe functions could be executing at the time the signal occurs.

Comment: @R so how to make sure (safely) that a stream is flushed on eg. a SIGINT?